# How to disable a button if the user entered input is not valid email using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add email validation to the input field and based on that disable the add button if the email entered by user is wrong.

below you can see my code,

```
function Parent() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const onEmailChange = (event: any) => {
        setEmail(event.target.value);
    };

   const isDisabled = email.length === 0;

    return (
         <Input
             type="email"
             value={email}
             onChange={onEmailChange}
             placeholder="Insert user email"
         />
         <button disabled={isdisabled}>Add</button> //add button to be disabled when      user input email is wrong
   );
```

}

I want to make sure i have basic email validation for the input and be able to enter only numbers, ''.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

image for the error unnecessary escape character
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` in order to check if the input value is an email by using the `onChange()` property.

```
import React from "react";

const regex = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/i;

export default function App() {

  const [isDisabled, setDisibility] = React.useState(true);

  const checkEmail = e => {
    setDisibility(!regex.test(e.target.value));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={checkEmail} placeholder="email address" />
      <button disabled={isDisabled}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-sun-votmt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: thanks this gives me error in the regex unnecessary escape character. and not allowing me to type in input field. attached the image for errors in my question

Comment: @saritha it's a lint rule (`no-useless-escape`) that you can disable, but I also updated the regex in my code without the escape chars so you can try it now (updated the sandBox as well)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this but I would advise keeping a track of the disabled state of the button in its own state which is initialized to true.

Now change the disabled state inside a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) which runs every time the email is changed and set it to true or false based on your validation.

```
import React from "react";

// Modify this function as per your needs
const validateEmail = email => typeof email === "string" && email.includes("@");

export default function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = React.useState(true);

  const onEmailChange = event => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsDisabled(!validateEmail(email));
  }, [email]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={onEmailChange}
        placeholder="Insert user email"
      />
      <button disabled={isDisabled}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the working prototype in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wildflower-qpu93?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: what is this validatorFunction(email) do? code for that?

Comment: if you want to check input format you can use regex, so;
`useEffect(() => {
           const isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(email)
           setIsDisabled(validation);
       }, [email]);`

this will be check input for email format like "abc@bla.bla".